# How to enter state array and sum objects' props?

Tags: javascript, arrays, state

That is the code:
I have order array in state, table which map it ,and now i need to summarize prices which are inside objects in array. It should be counted in "handleCount" function,without adding any extra state objects, and return true cost of orders. Then "newPrice"-(which store cost)should be passed to "handleSubmit function.

```js
const menuItems = [
      { id: 1, name: "Pizza", price: 40 },
      { id: 2, name: "Burger", price: 30 },
      {id:3 , name: "Taco", price:15},
      {id:4,name:"Cola",price:5}
    ];
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      order: []      
    };
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
         <label>
          What would u like to order: 
          <select price={this.state.price} name="list" onChange={this.addFood}>
            {menuItems.map((item) => (<option value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>))}
          </select>
        </label>
        <h1></h1>     
       <h1></h1>
        <output>{this.state.counter}</output>
        <h1></h1>
         <button onClick={this.handleCount}>count</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>submit</button>
<table size="sm" name="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>delete?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
     {this.state.order.map((item, index) => (
      <tr>
        <th ordersId={item.id}>{index}</th>
        <th name={item.name}>{item.name}</th>
        <th price={item.price}>{item.price}</th>
        
        <button onClick={this.handleChangeDelete({ index })} name="deleteButton" id={"delete"+index}>-</button>
      </tr>)
     )}
  </tbody>
</table>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleCount =(e)=>{
   let newPrice = this.state.order.map(price);
    order.reduce((x, y) => x + y)
   console.log(newPrice);
   return (newPrice);
    
  }
  addFood =(e)=>{
    //var integer = parseInt(this.state.price, 10);
    let newItem = menuItems.find((item) => item.id == e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      order: [...this.state.order, newItem]    
    });   
    console.log('state', this.state.order[0]);
  }
  handleChangeDelete =({ index }) => {
    //console.log(index);
    return (evt) => {
      let order = this.state.order;
      order.splice(index , 1);
      this.setState({
        order: order
      });
    };
};
  

    handleChangeSelect =(e)=> {
    this.setState({value: event.target.price});
      
  }
  handleSubmit =(event)=> {
    if(this.state.counter===0){
      alert('You did not order anything');
    }else{
    alert('Your order is ready, it costs   ' );
    event.preventDefault();
  }}
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

```
const menuItems = [
  { id: 1, name: "Pizza",  price: 40 },
  { id: 2, name: "Burger", price: 30 },
  { id: 3, name: "Taco",   price: 15 },
  { id: 4, name: "Cola",   price: 5  }
];

const pricesSum = menuItems => {
  return menuItems.reduce((prev, current) => {
             prev.price = prev.price + current.price;
             return prev;
           }
        ).price;
 }

const sum = pricesSum(menuItems);
```

More simple:

```
const pricesSum = menuItems => {
  let sum = 0;
  menuItems.forEach(item => 
    sum += item.price
);

  return sum;
}

const sum = pricesSum(menuItems);
```

> 90

Answer (score 0):

```js
const menuItems = [
  { id: 1, name: "Pizza",  price: 40 },
  { id: 2, name: "Burger", price: 30 },
  { id: 3, name: "Taco",   price: 15 },
  { id: 4, name: "Cola",   price: 5  }
];

console.log( sumByKey(menuItems) );
console.log( sumByKey(menuItems, "id") );
console.log( sumByKey(menuItems, "name") );

function sumByKey(arr, key){
  key = key || "price"; // (*1)
  let join = isNaN( arr[0][key] ) ? ", " : 0; // (*2)

  return arr.reduce(function(prev, elem){
    prev[key] = prev[key] + join + elem[key];
    return prev;
  })[key]; // (*3)
}
```

(*1): It will sum the "price" values by default, if `key` is undefined.

(*2): Checking the first element's `key` value. If it's not NaN - later we will place 0 between the sum of elements. And if it's NaN (String) - commas.

(*3): `.reduce` function will reduce the array up to one last element. And the function will show it's `key` value.